# Triple negation needed to retrieve text node

Tags: jquery

Wanting to get text node from an element using some 'readable' method, i came to this strange behaviour i cannot explain.

### -jsFiddle-

Using following HTML markup:

```
<div>text node <b>and b element</b></div>
```

A text node isn't a DOM element, so i was wondering if this works:

```
var textnode = $('div').contents().filter(':not(*)'); //returns jq empty set
```

It fails even if using `.filter('*')` and doesn't return the text node but other element (`b`).

So testing it, i used [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method, which i wasn't sure it works or not for text node:

```
var textnode = $('div').contents().not('*'); //returns jq empty set
```

Let admit it. **But** this one returns the text node:

```
var textnode = $('div').contents().not(':not(:not(*))'); //returns text node in set
```

**So why** `.not('*')` is failing while `.not(':not(:not(*))')` works **?** 
I cannot explain it.

*PS:* `.filter(':not(:not(:not(*)))')` fails while i was expecting it to work exactly as `.not(':not(:not(*))')`

Comment: Omg! A question from a legend! Why not `.contents()`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar But i'm using `contents()`. I could filter it by nodeType but my question is just regarding this strange behaviour. I must be missing something... :)  My former goal was just to find more handing way to `.contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType === 3; });`

Comment: Deleted my answers as I noticed I got back both elements. My fork for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/9tb5Lsnd/1/

Comment: @Twisty Thanks for your answer but my question is really why `.not('*')` isn't returning text node while `.not(':not(:not(*))')` will? I don't understand this behaviour

Comment: Per the API Page, *Selects all elements*, and the textNode is an element (and object). I think that `:not(:not(*))` is working since CSS does not have a selector for textNodes. It then returns the only element that can't be selected by CSS.

Comment: My bet is that because `:not(:not (*))` (unlike `:not(simpleSelector)`) isn't valid CSS selector, jquery uses its own [:not()](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) pseudo selector. I will investigate it through jQuery source code when ill get more time in hands. Anyway, it won't explain why `.filter(':not(:not(:not(*)))')` doesn't work in this case

Comment: It looks like it has to do with  risSimple (`/^.[^:#\[\.,]*$/`) regex in `winnow()` internal method

Comment: It gets better: `.not(':not(*)')` returns the `b` element, `.not(':not(:not(:not(*)))')` returns both the `b` and `text` elements!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `.not(':not(:not(*))')` is not a simple selector (basically, it has more than one "part"), it is treated differently.

Simple selectors (like the `.filter(':not(*)')` and `.not('*')`) get passed to the `jQuery.filter()` function with a boolean indicator named `not`.
This indicator which wraps an additional `:not(...)` around the selector for `.not(selector)`.

`jQuery.filter()` returns nodes that filter through the selector. It has an additional check so it only ever returns nodes of nodeType 1 (elements).

For complex selectors (like `.not(':not(:not(*))')`), the mechanism works a bit differently; the selector gets passed to `jQuery.filter()` but the `not` boolean indicator is not set.
Instead, the nodes returned from `jQuery.filter()` are compared to the original list of nodes and filtered in or out depending on whether you used `.not()` or `.filter()`.
Since `jQuery.filter()` only ever returns elements, when comparing to the original list of nodes it can't find any match for the text element.
In the case of your `.not(':not(:not(*))')`, this means that according to this logic, the text node should not be filtered out, because it's not in the list of nodes to be filtered out that was returned by `jQuery.filter()`.

The reason for these different mechanism is probably that you can't just wrap `:not(...)` around any complex selector; it could change the intended meaning.

Though they do state in the [`.contents()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) that text nodes are not supported by most of the rest of jQuery.
It could be solved by explicitely only ever returning nodeType 1 nodes from the `winnow` function.

Original jQuery 1.11.3 code:

```
function winnow( elements, qualifier, not ) {
    //...

    return jQuery.grep( elements, function( elem ) {
        return ( jQuery.inArray( elem, qualifier ) >= 0 ) !== not;
    });
}
```

Changed code:

```
function winnow( elements, qualifier, not ) {
    //...

    return jQuery.grep( elements, function( elem ) {
        return ( jQuery.inArray( elem, qualifier ) >= 0 ) !== not && elem.nodeType === 1;
    });
}
```

I don't know if this qualifies as a bug, but it is atleast a solvable inconsistency in jQuery. You might want to report it to jQuery.

Comment: It looks like relevant answer. I guess the doc should specify to not nesting jquery `:not()` pseudo selector. Thx for this detailed answer.

Comment: @A.Wolff I haven't tested it, but I don't think it's just the nested `:not()`s. Any complex `.not()` filter should have the same problem of leaving in all the nodes not of nodeType 1.

Comment: Ya sure, same issue using any complex selector.